# Finding a location of a string in another string using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to write a code so a person can find the location of his birthday in the digits of pi.
So I tried to create a function which takes a string as input (by pressing a button), for example "0211" and the output should then be the location. Let's say 288. This is what I have done so far but it doesn't work. Any ideas? Thank you.

```js
function myFunction() {
  var str = "31415926...";
  var n = str.indexOf("BIRTHDAY");
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = n;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to enter your birthday.</p>
    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Type your birthday</button>
    
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What, more precisely, doesn't work?

Comment: [Seems to work if you actually HAVE enough the digits of Pi and you pass something that's contained in them](https://jsbin.com/lulanoqida/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanks, but I should add a button where the person can type in the 4 digits of his birthday. Fe 02-12.

Comment: I don't think that's related to Pi or finding stuff in a string. You can use `prompt()` or have an input where the user can type it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following:

```js
function myFunction() {
let input = document.getElementById('birthday').value;
let output = document.getElementById('demo');

let str = '34534536456336345634634563456';

output.textContent = str.indexOf(input);
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to enter your birthday.</p>
    
<label for="birthday">Enter birthday</label>
<input type="text" id="birthday">
<button onclick="myFunction()">get position</button>
    
<p id="demo"></p>
```